# Juju charms - how to run and debug reactive charm

Tags: python, juju, debugging

I'm developing a juju charm in python using a reactive pattern. All my hooks are called using decorators provided by 'basic' base layer. When trying to deploy the charm I encountered an error. In order to solve the error I used 'juju debug-hooks' and 'juju dhx -r' (dhx debugging plugin) but I can't find a way to run charm code using python following reactive pattern...
As I understand, (when using dhx for debugging for example) the charm execution is returned to the state exactly before the hook that caused an error and the developer is logged in into a remote debugging session. It is on the developer to run hooks. Normally these hooks would be under /hooks directory and would be run by just executing them. This isn't possible using reactive pattern, since there is no entry point for hooks but everything is just a cascade of reactions to states...

**How do I run a juju charm code written in python following reactive pattern during a debugging session?**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because in some way my `set_state('myservice.installed')` was triggered even when I got the error that my installation hook had failed. I did not found a specific solution to run a certain piece of code but a good workaround can be to change the event that would normally trigger your code and rerun `hooks/install`. I only tried it with `juju debug-hooks` and not with `juju dhx`, but that did the job for me.

In my case I saw that my current state was set to 'Installed'. By changing my event to trigger the code I was able to rerun my Install-hook. In my `debug-hooks` session I could then see where my hook failed.

```
from charms.reactive import when, set_state
import charms.apt

@when('myservice.installed')
def install():
    charms.apt.queue_install(['some-package'])
    // do some extra stuff
    set_state('myservice.installed')
```

Answer (score 0):

## How do I run a reactive charm during a debugging session?

**You run a reactive charm by running a hook in the `hooks/` directory.** That hook will start the reactive framework and initiate the "cascade of states".

The hook files in the `hooks/` directory are created by `layer-basic` and by `charm build`. **Make sure to include `layer-basic`** in your `layer.yaml` file if the hook files aren't present in the `hooks/` directory.

You can find more information about debugging reactive charms in [the Juju docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.2/developer-debugging).